# Django Template loader doesn't have "get_contents()" function implemented. Is there a substitute?

Tags: python, django, loader

I am working on upgrading some older Django code however I am running into issues with the loader function "get_contents()" as it has apparently been deprecated. I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I create a new child claqss from that loader and implement the function myself or is there another way?

I have basically tried looking this problem up on google and the few answers I've come across have been somewhat vague.

I can't show much code, as this is a private project, but I can show one line with the names changed.

```
templateVariable = loader.get_template('appName/filename.txt')
```

This is the error I'm getting when I try and run the function:

```
'Loader' object has no attribute 'get_contents'
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that there was a custom loader being used in the project and the get_contents() function hadn't been implemented yet. Another mystery solved.